# How to keep the keyboard open after completed event fired on a Xamarin entry?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, keyboard, xamarin.forms

Everyone just want to hide the keyboard, but it closes automatically.

I want to keep the keyboard open and keep the entry focused after the completed event fired on a Xamarin entry control or in other words, I do not want the entry control blurred.

Comment: What is your completed event? Can't you just call `.Focus()` on the entry after this event has finished?

Comment: @JimBobBennett The completed event gets the .Text from the entry and .Add it to a Listview! I have tried your suggestion but that just makes the keyboard reappearing, so the closing/opening animation and the UI redraw is still present.